# Why Jetty taking java class reference from maven created target folder?

Tags: java, maven, jetty, embedded-jetty

I am using Jetty eclipse plugin and generally other server will pick classes from `/src/main/java` folder,but in Jetty case its totally different its picking classes from the `/target/classes` folder .Is this right if yes then

1. How it will pick the properties file needed in web project?
2. Should i have to manually copy the dependent project jar file into the Jetty server lib directly ?

[image]

Jetty plugin i am using
[image]

Comment: `src/main/java` and `target/classes` indicate maven use.  what "Jetty eclipse plugin" are you referring to? (there's 4 known eclipse plugins, 2 maven plugins, and 3 gradle plugins)

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt I added which Jetty plugin i am using